# Is it proper to have shingles at the bottom of the valley where the fascia is be 3 inches above the roof deck?

Tags: roof, roofing, shingles

[image]The shingles at the bottom of the valley are not laying on the roof deck, they are bridging across leaving a large gap between the shingles and roof.
Is this normal?

Comment: Hi @PPhil - perhaps a photo or drawing would explain your issue?

Comment: No.  Fascia should be level with the deck.  First good wind and say goodbye to shingles.  Will also allow water to pool and run under the shingles and possible leak in the house.  Add pictures to your question so we can be sure.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I apologize. I thought I had uploaded the picture before, I believe it is showing now.

Comment: That looks like a mess waiting to happen, the shingles will break if stepped on and may break from stress. I was taught to flash valleys and either leave a gap and allow the water to run down the flashing or to edge lap flat , looks a little better but more work and tends to plug more easily, that is just a mess.